# How can I make nested asynchronous calls using Asyncio in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter, python-asyncio

I've created a Jupyter Notebook that benchmarks two different versions of a model code to see if they produce the same results by running through a set of example problems. For example, I am running the reference model 'RF' and the benchmark model 'BM' on the set of example problems (e.g. Example1 to Example10), and then  compare the results to see if they're different.

So far, I managed to get the following working:

- loop over the example problems
- get RF and BM run to run the current example asynchronously using asyncio
- wait for both RF and BM to complete
- gather the results and compare them

But can't get it to run the set of examples in a nested fashion so that each set of examples can run independently.

A very simplified version of what I have:

```py
#Ex_cases is a list of example cases defined elsewhere 
#RF is the reference model 
#BM is the benchmark model

def compare(RF, BM)
    #do some comparisons on the results 
    return comparison

async def Run_sim(model, case): #run the model for the specified case
    result = run_model(model,case)
    return result

for (i,n) in enumerate(Ex_cases)
    RF_task = asyncio.create_task(Run_sim(RF, Ex_cases[i]))
    BM_task = asyncio.create_task(Run_sim(RF, Ex_cases[i]))

    results = await asyncio.gather(RF_task,BM_task)
    RF_res = results[0]
    BM_res = results[1]

    comparison = compare(RF_res,BM_res)
    print(comparison)
```

The above works reasonably well and cuts the run time in about half. What I'd like to figure out how to do is make the for loop asynchronous as well, so that each iteration of the for loop can run independently, but the parallel RF and BM tasks within the loop must run complete before getting to the compare function. Unfortunately, I find the asyncio documentation rather opaque for this task.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the body of that `for` loop as a coroutine and call the `asyncio.gather()` for all coroutines, like the following example.(I corrected a typo in the original code and refactored somewhat.)

```
async def run_sim(model, case):
    result = run_model(model, case)
    return result

async def run_sims_and_compare(case):
    RF_res, BM_res = await asyncio.gather(run_sim(RF, case), run_sim(BM, case))
    comparison = compare(RF_res, BM_res)
    print(comparison)

await asyncio.gather(*[run_sims_and_compare(case) for case in Ex_cases])
```

As a side note, you can pass a coroutine directly to the `asyncio.gather()`.
And don't forget you are using only single thread by doing this. See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools) for using multiple threads. But I don't know whether it is fully supported in Jupyter.

Comment: Thanks @relent95! I will try to implement this and let you know how it goes.